# Processbuilder in Java is not throwing up the sub process exception

Tags: java, exception, processbuilder

I am trying to execute a jar file in Java using ProcessBuilder. Now, Whenever the sub process called by the ProcessBuilder, throws any exception, the ProcessBuilder don't catch the exception and execution keeps on proceeding continuously.

Below is my code:

```
try {
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", CommonConstants.jarFileLocation,
                fileEntry.getAbsolutePath(), CommonConstants.commonFileLocation);       
        Process p = pb.start();         
    } 
catch (Exception e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
```

The catch block is suppose to print any exception whenever the sub process throws any. However, it never does.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Done it for printing in console....

I used the ProcessBuilder inheritIO method which sets the source and destination for sub process standard I/O to be the same as those of the current Java process.

Hence the modified code...

```
try {
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", CommonConstants.jarFileLocation,
                fileEntry.getAbsolutePath(), CommonConstants.commonFileLocation).redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);       
        Process p = pb.start();         
    } 
catch (Exception e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
```

However, need it to be caught by the catch block.
Need Help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not caught in the `catch` block because the sub-process will not throw any exceptions other than `IOException` when you start it and `InterruptedException` when you wait for its completion. You would have to parse whatever you get from the `stderr` stream and throw appropriate exceptions yourself.
This means you have to know exactly what your errors look like and act accordingly.
Below is an example in Java 8 with `CompletableFuture`. You can also use `Thread`s to read from the input stream and parse your error messages accordingly.

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", 
                                CommonConstants.jarFileLocation,
                                fileEntry.getAbsolutePath(), 
                                CommonConstants.commonFileLocation);

    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
    
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> errorMessages = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream))) {
            return br
                    .lines()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    });

   int exitCode = process.waitFor();
   
   for (String errorMessage: errorMessages.get()) {
        if (errorMessage.contains("reason X")) {
             throw new ReasonXException(); // assuming we defined this custom exception somewhere
        }
        if (errorMessage.contains("reason Y")) {
             throw new ReasonYException(); // assuming we defined this custom exception somewhere
        }
        throw new Exception(errorMessage);
   }

   if (exitCode != 0) {
       throw new Exception("Program exited with a non-zero status code");
   }
}
catch (Exception e) {           
    e.printStackTrace();   // catching generic Exception here for brevity, you should catch more specific exceptions in your own code.
}
```

Note that this is not a universal solution and might have to be altered to match your use case. This example works only if there is a single error message per line. So if that's not the case for you, then you'd have to adapt the error message handling logic accordingly, probably having a more complex mechanism of mapping them to the "final" list of error messages.

Also, if you want to use this approach, do NOT call `inheritIO()` on the `Process` as `getErrorStream()` will then return an empty stream and you wouldn't be able to fetch any error messages.